# bcrypt integration in Grails using spring-security-bcrypt plugin

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security, bcrypt

I want to use bcrypt hashing algorithm in my grails project instead of its defaultSHA-256 message digest algorithm. To enable bcrypt, you just use the `grails install-plugin spring-security-bcrypt` command.

You can customize keying rounds by adding this to `BuildConfig.groovy`:

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.password.bcrypt.logrounds = 15
```

My question is, is that all I need to do to set bcrypt as my password algorithm? Does it automatically use the bcrypt algorithm when I use this method from the domain class generated by spring-security-core:

```
springSecurityService.encodePassword(params.password)
```

How do I check if bcrypt is working on my project?

Comment: That plugin is... 'deprecated' in newer versions of spring security as someone (me) has added it to the main plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You also need to add

```
grails.plugins.springsecurity.password.algorithm='bcrypt'
```

Comment: Another question, Do I still need to use a Password Encoder when decypt the password hashed by bcrypt? In situations like, a registrant tries to log-in to the system and I need to compare the registrant's entered password to the password saved in the database which is hashed by Bcrypt to check if the one who tries to log-in is authorized.

Comment: No, it's done by Spring Security itself. You don't need to make you own authorization, you will get authorized user, with valid password

Comment: thanks for sharing, even though my question sounds noobie. haha. thanks a lot! 
you are a really big help. :)

Comment: uhhhmm last question, how to find out if my bcrypt in my project has take effect? thanks..

Comment: Hm, probably the best way is to take a look at database table, and see