# No such algorithm - bcrypt

Tags: java, spring, grails, java-security, grails-3.1

I'm using Spring Security with bcrypt for password security.

It's actually in a Grails application. When the application starts up I get:

"No such algorithm [bcrypt]"

I traced the error to the code in Spring security:

```
    try {
        return MessageDigest.getInstance(algorithm);
    }
    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No such algorithm [" + algorithm + "]");
    }
```

How do I install bcrypt into Java Security?

I'm running Oracle JDK 1.8.0_73-b02 on CentOS 7.

Comment: Oracle documentation shows bcrypt not included in base version: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/StandardNames.html#MessageDigest

Comment: Grails seems to a bcrypt plugin for Grails. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10242519/bcrypt-integration-in-grails-using-spring-security-bcrypt-plugin

Comment: Looks like plugin not available for Grails 3 yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the code:

```
messageDigestPasswordEncoder(MessageDigestPasswordEncoder, conf.password.algorithm) {
    encodeHashAsBase64 = conf.password.encodeHashAsBase64
    iterations = conf.password.hash.iterations
}
```

By default the Grails 3 spring-core plugin configures conf.password.algorithm="bcrypt"

I thought I had overridden it in my config but that was in Config.groovy. In grails 3 config needs to be moved to application.groovy